# H2 Database created in JAVA not found in H2 Console?

Tags: java, database, h2

Currently have a simple Java Program that creates an H2 Database like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stm = null;
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:D:/H2db/test", "sa", "sa");
    stm = conn.createStatement();
} catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I see the files created within the directory. Yet, when attempting to access this same Database from the H2 Console (`localhost:8082`) and input both
`jdbc:h2:D:/H2db/test` and `jdbc:h2:D:\H2db\test`, I get an error saying:

```
Database `D:/H2db/test` not found, either pre-create it or 
allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments)
```

Anyone know why I cant access the Database through the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That piece of code is just for connection to a previously created database. To successfully connect to it you should create it first.

```
$ java -cp bin/h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.Shell
Welcome to H2 Shell 1.4.199 (2019-03-13)
Exit with Ctrl+C
[Enter]   jdbc:h2:mem:test
URL       jdbc:h2:D:/h2db/test
[Enter]   org.h2.Driver
Driver    
[Enter]   sa
User      
Password
```

Then and only then you'll be able to connect to it through your java application.

Comment: But then establishing a connection to a newly made Database through the Java program and then running this query: `SELECT * FROM TEST` returns "Table TEST not found"

Comment: Nevermind, seemed to get it working now! How do I create a database then if it doesn't exist?